# apache beam broadcast a spacy model as side inputs in Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spacy

I am using python sdk and trying to broadcast a spacy model (~50MB). The job will run on Dataflow.
I am new to beam, and based on my understanding: we cannot load large objects in map function and we cannot load them before submitting jobs since job sizes are capped. Below is a workaround to "lazy-loading" large objects on workers.

```
        ner_model = (
            pipeline
            | "ner_model" >> beam.Create([None])
            | beam.Map(lambda x: spacy.load("en_core_web_md"))
        )

        (
            pipeline
            | bq_input_op
            | beam.Map(use_model_to_extract_person, beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(ner_model))
            | bq_output_op
        )
```

but I got
`Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h. Please check the worker logs in Stackdriver Logging.`
However, there are no Stackdriver logs generated at all. Am I on the right track?

Edit:
I am using apache-beam 2.23.0

Comment: Can you let me know which version of Apache Beam are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that your worker has not enough memory. Probably you could solve it, using a worker with more memory. Currently the default worker is `n1-standard-1` with only 3.75 GB RAM.

The related `PipelineOption` is:

> workerMachineType     String
>
> The Compute Engine machine type that Dataflow uses when starting
> worker VMs. You can use any of the available Compute Engine machine
> type families as well as custom machine types.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but still doesn't work. also I feel broadcasting 40MB is not super memory expensive?

Comment: Which size did you tested? I'd once to process parquet files, where each was < 20 MB, but anyway had to use a worker with 16GB. The python libraries do need a lot additional memory, beside the pure data.

Comment: that's really good to know. I tried n1-standard-4 with 16GB memory. probably still not big enough?

Comment: Maybe try loading the pipeline locally and see how much memory that takes. You could also try with a smaller model to see if that is your issue. It is possible that, to move it between workers, it is trying to *pickle* the model, which could be horribly inefficient. See an alternative answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large, static model to load, you could try using a [DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms) and loading it in `DoFn.setUp` rather than pass it as a side input.

Comment: does python sdk support that?

Comment: Yes, this is supported in both Java and Python.

Comment: This sounds like an alternative to side input. Could you point me more resources on the difference between them?